# SQL (in Progress Database) - How to use Where clause on calculated field

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I'm pretty new to SQL, I've been using SQL on a Progress Database, I have the following code below:

```
Select pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col", Sum(pub."GL_Table"."Amount_Col"), ROUND((pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col")/100,0) AS "Year", MOD(pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col",100) As "Month"
FROM pub."GL_Table"
GROUP BY pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col"
ORDER BY pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col"
```

I want to only display only those rows with `"Year"` 2017

I have tried the below (but I receive errors):

```
Select * FROM (
Select pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col", Sum(pub."GL_Table"."Amount_Col"), ROUND((pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col")/100,0) AS "Year", MOD(pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col",100) As "Month"
FROM pub."GL_Table"
GROUP BY pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col"
ORDER BY pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col"
)
WHERE "Year" = 2017
```

Can anyone assist me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Progress DB?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Are you using the SQL89 engine in the 4GL editor, or the SQL92 engine? You certainly can't use a where with a calculated field like that, but you might be able to use HAVING instead. I'm fairly sure the SQL89 engine won't allow the sort of subqueries being suggested, but the SQL92 might do.

Answer (score 1):

Although a subquery is one approach, you can also reference the calculation in the where clause instead.

```
Select pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col", Sum(pub."GL_Table"."Amount_Col"), ROUND((pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col")/100,0) AS "Year", MOD(pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col",100) As "Month"
FROM pub."GL_Table"
WHERE ROUND((pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col")/100,0) = 2017
GROUP BY pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col"
ORDER BY pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the subquery alias. And the order by clause should be applied outside the subquery.

```
select *
from (
    select "gm-accno",
        "gt-accmth",
        Sum("gt-amount"),
        ROUND(("gt-accmth") / 100, 0) as "Year",
        MOD("gt-accmth", 100) as "Month"
    from pub."glsytr"
    group by "gm-accno",
        "gt-accmth"
    ) t
where "Year" = 2017
order by "gm-accno",
    "gt-accmth"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you need column aliases and maybe table aliases.  I am not intimately familiar with Progress, but the following seems more correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col",
             Sum(pub."GL_Table"."Amount_Col") as "Amount", 
             ROUND((pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col")/100, 0) AS "Year", 
             MOD(pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col", 100) As "Month"
      FROM pub."GL_Table"
      GROUP BY pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col"
      ORDER BY pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col"
     ) ym
WHERE "Year" = 2017
```